# site enlarges when downloading something in chrome

Tags: html, css

i have a problem with my site
the site works fine

but when i go to this page
http://sandergouman.nl/#AboutMe

and then you press hier downloaden and when you get the bar of chrome when you download a file the site becomes bigger
the site becomes bigger

but i dont know in what code the problem is
i have my index.html here:

```
<!--
    Astral by HTML5 UP
    html5up.net | @n33co
    Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HomePage</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/init.js"></script>

        <noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-desktop.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-noscript.css" />

        </noscript>


      <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="games/racegame/foto/fotozonder.PNG">
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>



        <!-- Wrapper-->
            <div id="wrapper">

                <!-- Nav -->
                    <nav id="nav">
                        <a href="#me" class="icon fa-home active"style=color:red><span>Home</span></a>
                        <a href="#work" class="icon fa-folder" style=color:red><span>Werk</span></a>
                        <a href="#contact" class="icon fa-envelope"style=color:blue><span>Contact</span></a>
                        <a href="#AboutMe" class=" icon fa-question-circle"style=color:blue><span>Over Mij</span></a>
                    </nav>

                <!-- Main -->
                    <div id="main">

                        <!-- Me -->
                            <article id="me" class="panel">
                                <header>
                                    <h1>Sander Gouman</h1>
                                    <p><font color="SVG">Welkom op mijn website.<br> Hier kunt u delen van mijn werk zien.</font></p>

                                </header>

                            </article>

                            <!-- over mij -->
                            <article id="AboutMe" class="panel">
                                <header>
                                    <h1>Sander Gouman</h1>
                                </header>
                                <p><font color="SVG">Ik ben Sander Gouman en ik woon in Amersfoort.<br>Ik ben 2e jaars student gamedeveloper aan het Grafisch Lyceum in Utrecht.<br> Ik werk met het programma Unity. Hierin zijn alle spellen op deze website gemaakt.<br> U kunt een pdf van mijn CV <a href="CV_Sander_Gouman.pdf" download>hier downloaden.</a></font></p>

                                <ul id="skill">
                                <li><span class="bar unity"></span><h3>Unity C#</h3>
                                <li><span class="bar html-css"></span><h3>Html // Css</h3>
                                <li><span class="bar testing"></span><h3>3D</h3>
                                </li>   
</ul>

                            </article>

                        <!-- Work --> 


                                <article id="work" class="panel">
                                <header>
                                    <h2>Werk</h2>
                                </header>
                                <p>

                                </p>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="4u">
                                            <div class="container">
                                                <div class="test revealUpFull">
                                                        <img src="games/racegame/foto/fotozonder.PNG" width="260" height="195" />
                                                        <span class="title"><a href="game1.html">Racegame<br /><i class="icon fa-clock-o"></i> 8 Weken<br><i class="icon fa-calendar"></i> 29-1-2015</a></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>  
                                        </div>
                                            <div class="4u">
                                            <div class="container">
                                                <div class="test revealUpFull">
                                                        <img src="games/top_down_shooter/foto/fotozonder.png" width="260" height="195" />
                                                        <span class="title"><a href="game3.html">Top down shooter<br /><i class="icon fa-clock-o"></i> 3 Weken<br><i class="icon fa-calendar"></i> 8-11-2014</a></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>  
                                        </div>
                                                <div class="4u">
                                            <div class="container">
                                                <div class="test revealUpFull">
                                                        <img src="games/fps_shooter/foto/fotozonder.PNG" width="260" height="195" />
                                                        <span class="title"><a href="game2.html">Fps shooter<br /><i class="icon fa-clock-o"></i> 8 Weken<br><i class="icon fa-calendar"></i> 11-5-2014</a></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>  
                                        </div>




                                    </div>

                            </article>


                        <!-- Contact -->
                            <article id="contact" class="panel">
                                <header>
                                    <h2>Contact Me</h2>
                                </header>

                                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2445.617108940998!2d5.3693015999999965!3d52.19583220000001!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47c646d54f5f74b3%3A0x24f74fcdc9277232!2sRabouwgaarde%2C+3824+Amersfoort!5e0!3m2!1snl!2snl!4v1426155136287" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0" align="right"></iframe>
                                <P STYLE="text-align: left;">Bedankt voor het bekijken van mijn website. Wilt u contact met mij opnemen vul dan het contactformulier hier beneden in.</P>
                            <form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">

                                    <div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="6u">
                                                <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Name" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="6u">
                                                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="12u">
                                                <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="12u">
                                                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="8"></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="12u">
                                                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </article>




                    </div>




                <!-- Footer -->
                    <div id="footer">
                        <ul class="copyright">
                            <li>&copy; Sander Gouman All rights reserved.

                        </ul>
                    </div>

            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

and my style.css:

```
@charset 'UTF-8';
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,300italic,400italic');
@import url('font-awesome.min.css');

/*
    Astral by HTML5 UP
    html5up.net | @n33co
    Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
*/


/*********************************************************************************/
/* Basic                                                                         */
/*********************************************************************************/

    body
    {
        background-image:           url('images/overlay.png'),      url('images/bg.jpg');
        background-repeat:          repeat,                         no-repeat;
        background-size:            auto,                           100% 100%;
    }

        body.is-loading *
        {
            -moz-transition: none !important;
            -webkit-transition: none !important;
            -o-transition: none !important;
            -ms-transition: none !important;
            transition: none !important;
            -moz-animation: none !important;
            -webkit-animation: none !important;
            -o-animation: none !important;
            -ms-animation: none !important;
            animation: none !important;
        }

    body,input,textarea,select
    {
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: SVG; /*#777777;*/
    }

    strong, b
    {
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #363636;
    }

    h1, h2, h3, h4,h5, h6
    {
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #363636;
    }

    blockquote
    {
        border-left: solid 0.5em #ddd;
        padding: 1em 0 1em 2em;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    em, i
    {
        font-style: italic;
    }

    hr
    {
        border: 0;
        border-top: solid 1px #ddd;
        padding: 1.5em 0 0 0;
        margin: 1.75em 0 0 0;
    }

    sub
    {
        position: relative;
        top: 0.5em;
        font-size: 0.8em;
    }

    sup
    {
        position: relative;
        top: -0.5em;
        font-size: 0.8em;
    }

    br.clear
    {
        clear: both;
    }

    p, ul, ol, dl, table, blockquote, form
    {
        margin-bottom: 2em;
    }

    /* Table */

        table
        {
            width: 100%;
        }

            table.default
            {
            }

                table.default tbody tr
                {
                    border-bottom: solid 1px #f4f4f4;
                }

                table.default td
                {
                    padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
                }

                table.default th
                {
                    text-align: left;
                    font-weight: 400;
                    padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
                }

                table.default thead
                {
                    border-bottom: solid 2px #f4f4f4;
                }

    /* Form */

        form
        {
        }

            form label
            {
                display: block;
                font-weight: 400;
                color: #363636;
                margin: 0 0 1em 0;
            }

            form input[type="text"],
            form input[type="email"],
            form input[type="password"],
            form select,
            form textarea
            {
                -webkit-appearance: none;
                border: 0;
                background: #FFFFFF;
                padding: 0.75em;
                width: 100%;
                -moz-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
                -webkit-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
                -o-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
                -ms-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
                transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
            }

            form input[type="text"],
            form input[type="email"],
            form input[type="password"],
            form select
            {
                line-height: 1.35em;
            }

            form input[type="text"]:focus,
            form input[type="email"]:focus,
            form input[type="password"]:focus,
            form select:focus,
            form textarea:focus
            {
                background: #f8f8f8;
            }

            form ::-webkit-input-placeholder
            {
                color: #999;
            }

            form :-moz-placeholder
            {
                color: #999;
            }

            form ::-moz-placeholder
            {
                color: #999;
            }

            form :-ms-input-placeholder
            {
                color: #999;
            }       

    /* Section/Article */

        section,
        article
        {
            margin-bottom: 3em;
        }

            section > :last-child,
            article > :last-child
            {
                margin-bottom: 0;
            }

            section:last-child,
            article:last-child
            {
                margin-bottom: 0;
            }

        header
        {
        }

            header > p
            {
                color: #aaa;
            }

    /* Image */



    .codeboxspace
    {

    min-width:1000px;
    max-width:1400px;
    width:95%;
    display:none;
    }
    #codebox
          {
          font-family: "Courier 10 Pitch", Courier, monospace; 
          font-size: 90%;
          line-height: 140%;
          white-space: pre;
          white-space: pre-wrap;
          white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
          white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
          background: #E0E0E0;
          display: block;
          padding: 0.5em 1em;
          border: 1px solid #bebab0;
          text-align:left;
          color:black;
          height : 100%;
          width:920px;
         } 

        .image
        {
            display: inline-block;
        }


            .image img
            {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .image.fit
            {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .image.featured
            {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0 0 2em 0;
            }

            .image.left
            {
                float: left;
                margin: 0 2em 2em 0;
            }

            .image.centered
            {
                display: block;
                margin: 0 0 2em 0;
            }

                .image.centered img
                {
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    width: auto;
                }

    /* Button */    

        input[type="button"],
        input[type="submit"],
        input[type="reset"],
        .button
        {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: #222222;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            border: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            outline: 0;
            -moz-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
            transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
        }

            input[type="button"]:hover,
            input[type="submit"]:hover,
            input[type="reset"]:hover,
            .button:hover
            {
                background-color: #333333;
            }

            input[type="button"]:active,
            input[type="submit"]:active,
            input[type="reset"]:active,
            .button:active
            {
                background-color: #444444;
            }

            input[type="button"].alt,
            input[type="submit"].alt,
            input[type="reset"].alt,
            .button.alt
            {
                background-color: #777777;
            }

                input[type="button"].alt:hover,
                input[type="submit"].alt:hover,
                input[type="reset"].alt:hover,
                .button.alt:hover
                {
                    background-color: #888888;
                }

                input[type="button"].alt:active,
                input[type="submit"].alt:active,
                input[type="reset"].alt:active,
                .button.alt:active
                {
                    background-color: #999999;
                }

    /* List */

        ul.default
        {
            list-style: disc;
            padding-left: 1em;
        }

            ul.default li
            {
                padding-left: 0.5em;
            }

        ul.actions
        {
        }

            ul.actions li
            {
                display: inline-block;
                margin-left: 0.5em;
            }

                ul.actions li:first-child
                {
                    margin-left: 0;
                }

        ol.default
        {
            list-style: decimal;
            padding-left: 1.25em;
        }

            ol.default li
            {
                padding-left: 0.25em;
            }

/*********************************************************************************/
/* Icons                                                                         */
/*********************************************************************************/

    .icon {
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        .icon:before {
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            font-family: FontAwesome;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            text-transform: none !important;
        }

        .icon > .label {
            display: none;
        }

/*********************************************************************************/
/* Nav                                                                           */
/*********************************************************************************/

    #nav
    {
    }

        #nav a
        {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            width: 1em;
            height: 1em;
            line-height: 0.9em;
        }

            #nav a.icon:before
            {
                padding-right: 0;
            }

/*********************************************************************************/
/* Panels                                                                        */
/*********************************************************************************/

    #main
    {
        position: relative;

        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .panel
    {
        position: relative;
    }

    /* Me */

        #me
        {
        }

            #me .pic
            {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
            }

                #me .pic:before
                {
                    content: '';
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    background: url('images/overlay.png');
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    z-index: 1;
                }

/*********************************************************************************/
/* Footer                                                                        */
/*********************************************************************************/

    #footer
    {
        color: #ccc;
        color: rgba(255,255,255,0.45);
    }

        #footer a
        {
            color: #ddd;
            color: rgba(255,255,255,0.65);
            -moz-transition: color .25s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: color .25s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: color .25s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: color .25s ease-in-out;
            transition: color .25s ease-in-out;
        }

        #footer a:hover
        {
            color: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
        }

        #footer .copyright
        {
        }

            #footer .copyright li
            {
                display: inline-block;
            }

                #footer .copyright li:before
                {
                    display: inline;
                    content: '\2022';
                    opacity: 0.5;
                    padding: 0 0.75em 0 0.75em;
                }

                #footer .copyright li:first-child:before
                {
                    display: none;
                }



#skill { 
    list-style: none;
    font: 12px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
    width: 296px;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

#skill li { 
    margin-bottom:50px; 
    background:#e9e5e2;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#e1ddd9), to(#e9e5e2));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e1ddd9, #e9e5e2);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e1ddd9, #e9e5e2);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e1ddd9, #e9e5e2);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e1ddd9, #e9e5e2);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #e1ddd9, #e9e5e2);  
    height:20px; 
    border-radius:10px; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px #bebbb9 inset, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;   
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px #bebbb9 inset, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;    
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0px #bebbb9 inset, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;     
}

#skill li h3 { 
    position:relative; 
    top:-25px;
}

.bar { 
    height:18px; 
    margin:1px 2px;  
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px #fcfcfc inset, 0 1px 0 #bebbb9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px #fcfcfc inset, 0 1px 0 #bebbb9;    
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0px #fcfcfc inset, 0 1px 0 #bebbb9;       
}

.unity {
    width:80%; 
    -moz-animation:unity 2s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation:unity 2s ease-out;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FF0000), to(#FF0000));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FF0000, #FF0000);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FF0000, #FF0000);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FF0000, #FF0000);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FF0000, #FF0000);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #FF0000, #FF0000);
}

.html-css {
    width:50%;
    -moz-animation:html-css 2s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation:html-css 2s ease-out;
    background-color: #FF8000;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FF8000), to(#FF8000));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FF8000, #FF8000);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FF8000, #FF8000);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FF8000, #FF8000);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FF8000, #FF8000);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #FF8000, #FF8000);
}

.testing {
    width:20%;
    -moz-animation:testing 2s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation:testing 2s ease-out;
    background-color: #192AFF;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#192AFF), to(#192AFF));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #192AFF, #192AFF);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #192AFF, #192AFF);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #192AFF, #192AFF);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #192AFF, #192AFF);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #192AFF, #192AFF);
}

@-moz-keyframes unity       {0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:100%;}  }
@-moz-keyframes html-css    { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:100%;}  }
@-moz-keyframes testing         { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:100%;}  }

@-webkit-keyframes unity       { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:80%;}  }
@-webkit-keyframes html-css        { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:50%;}  }
@-webkit-keyframes testing       { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:20%;}  }



div.container {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 675px;
}
div.test {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 260px;
    height: 195px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
test {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
span.title {
    width: 260px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.9);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    font-family:"Lucida Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
div.test.revealUpFull span {

    height: 195px;
    width: 260px;
    bottom: -150px;
    display: block;
}
div.test.revealUpFull span a {
text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
}
div.test.revealUpFull:hover img {
    top: -150px;
}
div.test.revealUpFull:hover span {
   bottom: 0px;
}
```

if you need more files let me know
you can also inspect the source on my website if you need to see files

hope someone can help me

Comment: I went to the site with Chrome and clicked the "hier downloaden" link.  The CV document downloaded, but otherwise nothing happened.  Do you see this with a particular browser?  When you say the site gets bigger, is it like you're zooming in?

Comment: hi
this is before i click the button:
http://i60.tinypic.com/35hrdsj.png

and after i press downloaden and the bar shows i get this:
http://i58.tinypic.com/30ll26o.png

as you can see it looks like the white is becoming bigger or something

Comment: Take the body CSS out, and see if it reproduces. If it does, then move on to other parts to the CSS. The use of auto makes me wonder if it might be causing it, in conjunction with something else...

Comment: It's a little hard to see, but I think in my browser the size change happens immediately after I load the page.

Comment: i fixed it already there was something wrong in my init.js

thanks anyway